# Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3.

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3.
Searched in the following locations:

path:/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.pom
path:/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.jar
path:/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.pom
path:/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.jar
path:/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.pom
path:/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.jar

```
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.jar
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.pom
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.jar
https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.pom
https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.3/appcompat-v7-28.0.3.jar
```

Required by:
    project :app

P

Comment: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml - there is no 28.0.3 - the latest is 28.0.0

Answer (score 18):

28.0.3 doesn't exist.

Change your implementation to 28.0.0.

Answer (score 8):

You can check out the latest version of `appcompat-v7` there:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7?repo=google.

So, you can only find **appcompat-v7: 28.0.0**. (the information is valid on November 1, 2018)

You need to change `appcompat-v7: 28.0.3` to `appcompat-v7: 28.0.0`.
Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue by using this version of appcompat version.

com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the next code in your build.gradle (project)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    ...
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    ...
    }
}
```